# C language calculation in printf

Tags: c++, c, printf, operator-keyword

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int x;
x = (10+20)*(1.0/2);
printf("%d", x);
return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
15
```

and in another form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
printf("%d", (10+20)*(1.0/2));
}
```

the output is

```
0
```

`1.0/2` is `0.5` when calculate in integer variable `x`,
but `1.0/2` is `0` when calculate in `printf` with `%d` (I think...)

I cannot understand this situation...

In addition, when I change `%d` to `%f` in the second code, the output is `15.000000`

I'm using DEV C++ in Windows 8.

Comment: If you're using Dev-C++ then why do the title and tags reference C and why are you using `printf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `(10+20)*(1.0/2)` is `double`, but `"%d"` expects an `int`.

So, you need to cast to `int` :

```
printf("%d", (int) ((10+20)*(1.0/2)));
```

It works with `"%f"` because that expects a `double`.

Comment: The cast is good for C, but as the question also has the C++ tag, worth mentioning `std::cout << (10 + 20)*(1.0/2);` - the stream will automatically act in a type-appropriate way (outputting the correct `double` value representation.

Comment: I understood like "(10+20)*(1.0/2) is double, and %d can't print double, so the output is 0." Is it right? And is it OK to have non-integer value (like 0.5 in 30*0.5) during int variable calculation?

Comment: @SleepyBear Your understanding is mostly correct - the output is undefined behavior because the parameter type (`double`) doesn't match the expected type (`int`). Undefined behavior means anything is possible, including having `0` as output.

Answer (score -2):

as said before, your problem is casting issues.
since 1.0/2 = 0.5 --> it is translated to 0, as a result of int casting.
the right way to do it is either using a calculation function - that returns an integer, casting it to int (as proposed), or doing the calculations before the printf.

Comment: No that's not it. The OP is asking why the behaviour differs not why it yields a certain value. The problem is breaking the contract of `printf` and invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Different from prior answer, but thanks for answering to my question!